# Restart my Server every 2 Days

Tags: cron, reboot, restart, automatic

I want that my Server automatically restarts at 00:00 every second day and starts normal so that my Teamspeak and sinusbots starts.

I have already added some lines to my Crontab:

```
@reboot cd /home/ts3/ && ./ts3server_startscript.sh start
@reboot cd /etc/init.d && ./sinusbot start
```

Comment: Servers should have 100% up time. Why are you having to reboot to get Teamspeak and sinusbots to start? That's the *real* problem.

Comment: ^^^ This. I also don't quite understand why you would want to reboot to make some services start. Please try and explain why you need to reboot for that - or is it another problem altogether?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for this:

```
0 0 */2 * * reboot
```

Every 2 day on all weeks and months at 00:00 runs the reboot command.

The ones you already added to your `crontab` file are running 2 script each time you boot your system.

Comment: thats was the right command what i wa lloking for but did i mus write before the command an @reboot like in the other commands

Comment: Nope, that's the exact line you should use... by the way you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful to you ;)

Comment: so its 5 days later but the server doesent restarted. http://prntscr.com/fuazsy thats that wats stand in my crontab.

Comment: Change the `reboot` with `/sbin/reboot` that might get it to work ...

Comment: It needs to run as root, not from your user crontab. So sudo crontab -e and the command  /sbin/shutdown -r now